# Read Column values from excel file using selenium java

Tags: java, excel

I am trying to read column values from excel file which looks like this

[image]

This is my code for reading excel file

```
Xls_Reader d = new Xls_Reader("C:\\TestData.xlsx");
System.out.println(d.getRowCount("sheetname"));
String s1 = String.valueOf(d.getCellData("TC03", "Contract_ID",3));
s1 =(int)Double.parseDouble(s1) + "";
System.out.println(s1);
```

in this code i am able to get record of one row. But i need to print all the Row value. 
Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

What Jars you are using for this approach?

Comment: i am using POI 3.15

Answer (score 0):

I have following code to read data from `excel` using `apache poi` -

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
 {

         FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("your_file.xlsx"));
         XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis); // XSSFWorkbook for .xlsx file
         XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0); // open sheet 1

        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

               // Traversing over each row of XLSX file
                while (rowIterator.hasNext())
                {
                    Row row = rowIterator.next();

                       if(row.getRowNum()!=0) // skip title row
                       {
                           Iterator  cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

                           while (cellIterator.hasNext())
                            {

                               Cell cell = (Cell) cellIterator.next();

                               System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t");
                            }

                        }
               }

}
```

Note :- In my case cell in excel sheet formatted as `text` you can change `cell.getStringCellValue()` method as per your data.

Answer (score 0):

This method will be print all sheet of your excel document:

```
    public static void GetEmail() throws IOException{
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream("C:/path to your doc");
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(in);

        ExcelExtractor extractor = new ExcelExtractor(wb);
        extractor.setFormulasNotResults(false); // Read formulas
        extractor.setIncludeSheetNames(false);
        String text = extractor.getText();

       System.out.println(text);    
    }
```